# How do I install wallpapers from previous versions of Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, desktop-background

I would like to know how to install all wallpapers from previous versions of Lubuntu. I do not want the Ubuntu wallpapers.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the wallpapers, amongst other assets and artwork, from the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/Artwork/Incoming/Lucid/LxDesign) for every Lubuntu version ever.

Scroll down and find the released artwork section and click the version you want, then you will find a downloads section at the bottom of the next page.

Answer (score 1):

You can install "lubuntu-artwork" packages from repositories using Synaptic or apt.

For example, the description of "lubuntu-artwork-10-04" on Synaptic is:

Artwork for Lubuntu, contained the wallpaper and others specific images and
logos. 
This package contains theme of Lubuntu 10.04